# the column name of the largest number in each row of a data.frame

Tags: r

I want to get the column name of the largest number of each row.
for example,
A table could be

```
x = c(1,2,4,4,3 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,5,4 ) 
z = c(4,5,2,1,1 ) 
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
df
```

the results what I want to get is

```
  x y z cloumn_name
1 1 2 4 z
2 2 3 5 z
3 4 3 2 x
4 4 5 1 y
5 3 4 1 y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorised solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(column_name = names(df)[apply(df,1,which.max)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this with `base` R and `apply`

```
df$maxcol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) colnames(df)[which.max(x)])
> df$maxcol
[1] "z" "z" "x" "y" "y"
```

This is quite a simple solution, as you can see the `margin` parameter of `apply` is set to `1` which means that the function will be applied for all rows of `df`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(column_name = names(df)[which.max(c_across())])
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
      x     y     z column_name
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1     1     2     4 z          
2     2     3     5 z          
3     4     3     2 x          
4     4     5     1 y          
5     3     4     1 y
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be reached reshaping data, but it can be a bit long:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
      pivot_longer(-id) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(Var=ifelse(value==max(value),name,NA)) %>%
      select(c(id,Var)) %>%
      filter(!is.na(Var)) %>%
      filter(!duplicated(Var)) 
  ) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
  x y z Var
1 1 2 4   z
2 2 3 5   z
3 4 3 2   x
4 4 5 1   y
5 3 4 1   y
```